# Anyone got a sample Windows batch file for auto-deploying Collabnet repo to a file folder?

Tags: windows, svn, deployment, post-commit

I'm using CollabNet Subversion Edge on Windows 2008 … and trying to auto-deploy (so update from repo to folder) when any commits are made by developers using Tortoise SVN.

I've got a post-commit hook file in the correct repo /hooks folder.  The file is named post-commit.bat

The file has one line -

"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe" /command:update /path:"c:\wamp\www\thewebsite*" /closeonend:1 /outfile:"c:\csvn\update-logs\thewebsite-out.txt"

When I commit anything, it's timing out if I have the file present. If the file is not present, the commits work without any problem.  So that tells me the post-commit file is being called … and it's got a problem!

Anyone got a sample post-commit Windows batch file that can help me?  Or know how to solve my particular problem?

Comment: /outfile do not described in the update command. BTW, using CLI-client is a **more** easy way

Answer (score 0):

You should try testing your script by simply calling it from the command line and passing in the repo and version parameters. This might give you some more insight as to why it is timing out. For example:

```
script.bat PATH_TO_REPO REPO_VERSION
```

Also instead of using Tortoise, use the native SVN client library. In your script you can navigate to the folder you want to update, and call the "svn update" command. This will be more straightforward and not have to go through Tortoise just to make the update command back to the native library.

Try something like this:

```
cd "c:\wamp\www\thewebsite"
svn update
```

If your SVN server requires permissions you may need to pass these in your script as well.

Comment: Hi there

I never knew there was a native SVN command.  If I put the code you've suggested in a batch file, and run it manually, it works perfectly.

If I put the code in the post-commit.bat and so an SVN commit from my local PC into the repo, the commit never stops/times out.

Any ideas?

Thanks so far!

Comment: You might want to do the update in a new thread (not 100% sure how to do that from the shell) as a post-commit script wont return until it is complete. It is likely that the update is taking longer than the commit timeout allows. Also double check there aren't any inputs required as this might lock up the script so it never returns.